# How to make TFS vNext Builds to delete gated-checkin-shelvestes after successful build?

Tags: tfsbuild, shelveset, gated-checkin, vnext

In XAML Builds, the temp-auto-created shelvesets of Gated CheckIn builds, disappear automatically after the checkin. In vNext - they aren't.

Is there way to make them disappear automatically after successful checkin-build?

Answer (score 0):

For vNext builds, the temp-auto-created shelvesets will also disappear automatically after successful checkin-build. I test this at my side, it works correctly.

If the Gated CheckIn builds failed, then the Shelvessets will be remained.
So, please check if the temp-auto-created shelvesets are the ones failed to Gated CheckIn

Please reference below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: It didn't help. But it solved itself when we upgraded from TFS 2015 to TFS 2017.